# python etcd3 randomly fails with failed: grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with: status = StatusCode.UNKNOWN

Tags: python-3.x, etcd3

I have very simple setup. I have etcd 3.3 server. 
I have code in python (3.6) ive installed etcd3 version 0.10.0

```
import etcd3
data = etcd3.client(host='my.host.net', port=2379).get('/exesiting/key'))
print( data )
```

Key exsist, server address is ok.
This code fails randomly with follwing error

```
failed: grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.UNKNOWN
        details = "Failed to create subchannel"
        debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1557133790.170407000","description":"Failed to create subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":2715,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1557133790.170402000","description":"Empty update","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":270}]}"
```

What is wrong? Do i need to clean up connections somehow?